# Query RavenDB without using the studio interface

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

I am trying to view my sagas in the RavenDB management studio, and loading even the initial page, all that I see is this "Querying documents..." box with a continuous moving progress bar. I can not seem to get past it, going from page to page it does not go away. Is there a way to pull all of the saga data into a list so I can look at it? It appears the issue is that the saga documents are continuously being added.

I've looked into the HTTP API and the Linq adapters, but I guess I am looking for something that already exists that can easily peer into the server much like the silverlight studio, except not such a pain. I more or less just want to pull a snapshot of all the documents into some kind of readable list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find LINQPad 4 convenient, the RavenDB driver for LINQPad can be found here:

https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RavenDB-Linqpad-Driver

For the command line - cURL using dynamic indexes as explained here:

http://ravendb.net/docs/http-api/indexes/dynamic-indexes

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, go to `http://localhost:8080/docs`
You might need to install JsonView, but that should give you what you want.

Comment: `{ Settings: { Raven/DataDir: "~\Tenants\Movies" }, 
@metadata: 
{ 
@id: "Raven/Databases/Movies", 
Last-Modified: "2012-11-26T17:53:21.1140000", 
@etag: "00000000-0000-0800-0000-000000000002", 
Non-Authoritative-Information: false 
} 
},`

I see this information, what path do I need to see the documents for this particular database?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to know how to browse the data through REST call,

"localhost:8080/databases/{database-name}/docs/{dataset-name}/id"

example:

"localhost:8080/databases/testDB/docs/Sites/1" 
will give the json data for the "Sites" document

"localhost:8080/databases/testDB/docs/" 
will give the json data for all the documents in 
testDB.